# find and set the location of indicator in textBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program with a `TextBox` that when I get a spacial input, I need to edit the text.

So I did that, but then the indicator returned to the beginning of the text, which is not a good MMI.

I was wondering if there is a way to edit the text without changing the indicator position, or is there a way to set the indicator position in the `TextBox`?

I've tried to edit the text in several ways, but they all lead to the indicator getting back to the start of the text.

I couldn't find a way to influence the location of the indicator so I'm guessing that's impossible, but I might be wrong.

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the selection.  This would set the cursor to the 5th position, but select nothing:

```
textBox1.Select(5, 0);
```

Just make sure this is the last thing that happens before returning control to the user.  Perhaps accompanied by a call to `Focus` if necessary.

In your case, you'd also need to keep track of what that position should be...prior to added/modified text?  After it?  Just replace `5` with that number.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
int startPosition = textBox1.SelectionStart;
int selectionLength = textBox1.SelectionLength;

//do what ever you need
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.ToUpper();

//place cursor back in position
textBox1.Select(startPosition, selectionLength);
```

Hope it helps.